# Xamarin application with Google Maps API V2 randomly crashing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, google-location-services

I'm getting a random crash in my application. It seems the problem is linked to Google Maps but i'm not quite sure how to fix it.

The following is the relevant extract from the logcat of the Android device i'm running on:

```
08-14 01:26:36.285  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts210veltedx/gts210velte:7.0/NRD90M/T819YDXS2BRA4:user/release-keys'
08-14 01:26:36.285  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : Revision: '4'
08-14 01:26:36.285  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : pid: 27706, tid: 29076, name: GLThread 1754  >>> com.organisation.appName<<<
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x0   00000000bcc23760  x1   0000000000000010  x2   0000000000000018  x3   0000000000000010
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   00000000bcc23770  x7   0000000000000000
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000020  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000004
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x12  0000000000000004  x13  00000000ffffffff  x14  0000000000000000  x15  00000000bcc23760
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x16  0000007f97802b68  x17  0000007fac251f08  x18  0000000000000001  x19  0000000000000000
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x20  0000007f78cc198c  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000000000000001  x23  0000007f78cc197c
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x24  0000007f6bb39328  x25  00000000bcc23760  x26  0000000000000018  x27  0000000000000000
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     x28  0000007f6c3fec80  x29  0000007f6c8c4370  x30  0000007f9727270c
08-14 01:26:36.286  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     sp   0000007f6c8c4370  pc   0000007fac251f48  pstate 0000000080000000
08-14 01:26:36.736  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : 
08-14 01:26:36.736  3094  3094 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000001af48  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+64)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000000000019f708  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN20EsxVertexArrayObject18UpdateInternalVbosEPK17EsxDrawDescriptorjPK16EsxAttributeDesc+1512)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00000000002d5418  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN20A5xVertexArrayObject11CalcVfdRegsEPK17EsxDrawDescriptorP10A5xVfdRegsi+152)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00000000002dc7b0  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10A5xContext16ValidateVfdStateEPK17EsxDrawDescriptori+48)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00000000002eebf8  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10A5xContext13ValidateStateEPK17EsxDrawDescriptor+2680)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000002ef0b0  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10A5xContext18HwValidateGfxStateEPK17EsxDrawDescriptor+16)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0000000000135590  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxContext16ValidateGfxStateEPK17EsxDrawDescriptor+720)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0000000000127f84  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxContext19DrawArraysInstancedE11EsxPrimTypeijj+164)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00000000000fca2c  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glDrawArrays+108)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000000000001a674  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so (glDrawArrays+268)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 000000000334b3e8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x201a000) (com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl.glDrawArrays+148)
08-14 01:26:36.737  3094  3094 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 000000000037659c  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/oat/arm64/MapsDynamite.odex (offset 0x43a000)
```

From the backtrace above, it looks to be related to the glDrawArrays method. However, i'm not calling this directly so i've no idea why it's crashing.

Note that i am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 7.0) tablet and i'm using version 29.0.0.2 of the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I take it you've not managed to replicate this behavior while actually debugging your app?

Comment: Yes the above is from a debug session. It doesn't break on any specific line though. I've also added code to catch Android unhandled exceptions, but it doesn't break in there either

Comment: Yeah that kind of makes sense. You often see UI related exceptions skip global un-handled exception catches because they run through the Graphics Layer and then break so they tend to get reported straight back as SIGSEGV errors. That said, are you calling anything that uses glDrawArrays?

Comment: Possibly - I'm not making any calls directly to glDrawArrays but i am calling methods on Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap such as AddPolyline(PolylineOptions options), AddMarker(MarkerOptions options), AnimateCamera(CameraUpdate update),  MoveCamera(CameraUpdate update), AddCircle(CircleOptions options). I don't know if any of these call it